# Adsense in dynamically created (with JS) page

Tags: jquery, html, adsense

I'm creating a web page dynamically with JQuery (writing HTML modules outside of the content and appending them to containers).

The problem is that Adsense doesn't seem to like that and returns "Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto".

Here's an example code [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nicotinell/pen/xGpXXW?editors=101)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="content-hook" class="row"></div>
</div>

<div id="modules" class="hidden">
      <div id="content" class="col-xs-12">
        A sample content
      </div>
      <div id="ad-unit-1" class="col-xs-12">
        Ad unit goes here
       </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var modules = [ 
    { module: 'content', hook: 'content-hook', position: '1'},
    { module: 'ad-unit-1', hook: 'content-hook', position: '2'},
];

function byPosition(a, b) { return b.position-a.position; }
modules.sort(byPosition);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(modules, function(i, v){
            if(v.hook != '') {
                    $('#' + v.module).prependTo('#' + v.hook);
                }
        })
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work when you specify a width for the container div?

Comment: It's using Bootstrap, the container class is 100%. I fear that the Adsense code is loaded before the modules are in place (because its code is inline and my script is at the end of the document) thus making the ad unit container invisible. Therefore it's width is 0.

Comment: Can you put it after they're in place? If not, try first putting them in invisible divs (e.g. position: absolute, left:-100%;), then moving them

Comment: A quick way of checking, open chrome - and paste the document ready aspect of the code in after the page loads. If it enters without issue - then yes it is a precedence thing (code loads in before modules are in place).
If that's the case, might be worth using an observer